# Can you authenticate a React Native app with a 'Regular Web App' auth0 application?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, authentication, oauth-2.0, auth0

I am trying to set up auth0 authentication with my React Native app. The client has made the backend with ASP.NET, and set up a 'Regular Web App' application on auth0. I'm following the quickstart guide for 'Native/Mobile app' (https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/react-native) but it's not working. Do I need to have a 'Native/Mobile app' application on auth0 in order to connect a React Native app to it?

Thanks!